# Error CORS Api Node Localhost

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, api

Mi proyecto se encuentra corriendo en un servidor propio de nuestra empresa, lo que hice fue exponer el puerto para poder acceder desde afuera, pero cuando intento hacer peticiones por ejemplo la de loguin me encuentro con el siguiente error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://192.168.100.11:3001/api/users/login' from origin
> 'http://nipponcarsrl.ddns.net:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in
> more-private address space `private`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de mi APP

```
require('dotenv').config('.env'); // Variables de entorno
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const dbConnect = require('./config/mongo'); // Archivo de configuracion de BD
const path = require('path');

const app = express(); // Inicio del servidor

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front/build')));

// TODO: Main de rutas
const {
    damageDetailsRoutes,
    sectorDamageRoutes,
    severityCodeRoutes,
    damageCodeRoutes,
    damageTypeRoutes,
    damagesRoutes,
    usersRoutes,
    adminRoutes
} = require('./routes/Index');

app.use('/api/damage-details',damageDetailsRoutes);
app.use('/api/severity-code', severityCodeRoutes);
app.use('/api/sector-damage', sectorDamageRoutes);
app.use('/api/damage-code', damageCodeRoutes);
app.use('/api/damage-type', damageTypeRoutes);
app.use('/api/damages', damagesRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('*** Server running ***');
    console.log(`http://localhost/${process.env.APP_PORT || 3000}`);
})
dbConnect();
```

Archivo Login

```
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";

import Swal from "sweetalert2";

import axios from "axios";
import { Global } from "../../helpers/Global";

export const Login = () => {
  const { form, changed } = useForm({});

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = form;

    try {
      await axios.post(`${Global.url}users/login`, user).then((res) => {
        Swal.fire({
          position: "top-end",
          icon: res.data.status,
          title: res.data.msg,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1300,
          toast: true,
        });

        const { tokenSession, user } = res.data;
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", tokenSession);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
        window.location.reload();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      document.getElementById("formLogin").reset();

      Swal.fire({
        position: "top-end",
        icon: "error",
        title: error.response.data.msg,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1300,
        toast: true,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h4 className="text-bold">INICIO DE SESION</h4>
      <header className="justify-content-center py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
        <form onSubmit={login} id="formLogin">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-6">
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                  onChange={changed}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-6">
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  onChange={changed}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-end">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
              INGRESAR
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: El Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado (CORS) es un mecanismo que utiliza cabeceras HTTP adicionales para permitir que un user agent obtenga permiso para acceder a recursos desde un servidor. Un agente crea una petición HTTP de origen cruzado cuando solicita un recurso desde un dominio distinto, un protocolo o un puerto diferente al del documento que lo generó.

Fuente: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Ok, y como lo soluciono? necesito poder usar la api en mi servidor loca y que los empledos puedan acceder desde afuera.

Comment: Alguien que tenga acceso al servicio o a lo que estes intentando consultar. Que yo sepa por lo regular eso se soluciona por parte del BackEnd.

Comment: Hay formas por decirlo así de librarse de esos problemas de CORS pero es solo con fines de desarrollo ya en producción no te funcionaria.

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo: Tenia un servicio en C# el cual pues se conectaba a un BD y bla bla, luego desde un Front en `React` me pegaba a ese servicio pero cuando intente hacer una consulta me dio problemas de `CORS` (Por lo que describí arriba) entonces en el proyecto `C#` o sea el Back arregle eso agregando unas configuraciones en el `Program.cs`

Comment: Podrías subir el código de tu archivo server o index.js?
Podrías resolverlo utilizando el siguiente paquete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: @LuisS.Romero Pero tendría que construir ese servicio en Node no? o puede agregar eso directamente al Front?. Como especie de un puente entre el Servidor y su Front y habilitar los cors en ese "puente".

Comment: Ya tengo agregado la libreria de CORS, pero no funciona con eso

Comment: Es que tengo entendido que para eso tendrías que crear el servicio en Node y que ese se conecte al servidor (Ahí agregas la config para los cors) y luego desde el Front consumir ese mismo servicio que creaste.

Comment: Es que esta creado el servidor (back) en nodeJs, ahi subi el codigo del servidor

Comment: @FrancoSanchez El error de CORS es un mecanismo del navegador, se produce cuando se hace request a otros dominios diferentes del de origen,  por lo general una forma de resolver eso es añadiendo en el servidor lo que te pasé en el mensaje anterior.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero fijate que agregue CORS con el siguiente codigo app.use(cors());

Comment: y si cambias esto `const cors = require('cors');` por esto `import cors from 'cors'` a ver

Comment: Es que no estoy trabajando con EMC6

Comment: ah caray, bueno

Comment: Yo lo único que me pregunto es: ¿Porqué exponer una aplicación de NodeJS directamente a Internet? Esto se debe manejar mediante un servidor proxy inverso. Apache o nginx por ejemplo. Pero nunca, nunca, nunca, nunca exponer una app de Nodejs directamente.

Comment: El CORS en resumen sirve para controlar quién puede acceder a tu API o no, para ello debes configurar que encabezados son aceptados, los origenes y los metodos. Te dejo un articulo que explica como funciona CORS en Node js: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/ en resumen en tu api debes darle permisos a tu aplicación de front end para poder acceder a los metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado colocando el origin dentro de la configuración del cors

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
```

esto hará que este accesible desde cualquier origen.